# attach() and detach() don't update the model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Basically, I'm doing an ajax call that requests the Controller to add a certain quantity of "Artigo" (which means Product) to an Actividade (which is sort of a document).

They have a many-to-many relation.

The behavior should be the following:

- If the "Actividade" doesn't have the "Artigo", it should attach it and set the quantity in the pivot table;
- If the "Actividade" has it and the existing quantity summed with the incoming quantity is:

  - Above zero, it simply sums it;
  - Below zero, ignores it;
  - Exactly zero, detaches it;
- In all cases, the controller should return the updated list of "Artigo" attached to that "Actividade".

The following code works perfectly, but it runs extra queries to fetch the updated list of "Artigo" before returning the JSON.

```php
// Controller

public function ajaxAddArtigo() {
    if(Request::ajax()) {
        try {
            $actividade = Actividade::find(Input::get('actividadeId')); // Actividade is something like a "Document"
            $artigo = Artigo::find(Input::get('artigoId')); // Artigo is a product
            $actividade->addArtigo($artigo, intval(Input::get('qtd'))); // "qtd" is quantity

            // if quantity of the Artigo becomes 0, the Artigo is detached and this doesn't return the updated collection (with the Artigo now detached)
            // if the Artigo doesn't exist and quantity is a positive value, the Artigo gets attached, but this still doesn't return the updated collection (with the new Artigo attached)
            return Response::json($actividade->artigos);

            //return Response::json(Actividade::find(Input::get('actividadeId'))->artigos); // i must do this to return the updated list :(
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
        }
    }
}


// Model Actividade

public function addArtigo(Artigo $artigo, $quantidade = 1) {
    if($this->auth() || $this->authColab()) {
        $actArtigo = $this->artigos->first(function($i, $item) use($artigo) { // get the wanted Artigo from the related Artigo's (or not, if it doesn't exist)
            return $item->id == $artigo->id;
        });

        if(count($actArtigo)) { // if it exists
            if($actArtigo->pivot->quantidade + $quantidade >= 0) { // we will see the effect of summing the quantity (it can be a negative number)
                if($actArtigo->pivot->quantidade + $quantidade == 0) { // if it becomes 0, detach it
                    $this->artigos()->detach($artigo->id);
                } else { // if it becomes bigger than 0, just sum it
                    $actArtigo->pivot->quantidade += $quantidade;
                }
            }
        } else { // if it doesn't exist, add a new one as long as quantity is a cool value
            if($quantidade > 0) {
                return $this->artigos()->attach($artigo, [
                    'utilizador_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                    'quantidade' => $quantidade
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to tell Laravel also update the model when doing `attach()` and `detach()`?

Answer (score -1):

Once you've attached or detached make sure you SAVE the model using the save() method

Otherwise any changes or relationships are lost

Comment: I've even tried `->push()`. Still doesn't update the changes to the model.

Comment: Have you looked at `sync()` as an alternative? eg '$actArtgo->sync($id)` $id is an array of id's - removes the orphaned id's at the same time as attaching new id's.

Comment: I ended up doing Actividade::find() again :(

Comment: Can no one explain why attach() doesn't update the in-memory collection?